# What matlab variable stores the current working directory when opening matlab by clicking on an .m file?

Tags: matlab

If I open Matlab by clicking on an **.m** file, the current working directory of this session of Matlab is that of the **.m** file.  What variable in Matlab does store this path information?

If Matlab is already open and I click on an **.m** file to open it in the editor, the current working directory does not change.  I want it to change. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The current working directory is accessible via `pwd`.  For example:

```
>> currentDir = pwd
currentDir =
E:\Users\Jon\Documents\MATLAB
```

There is no way that I know of for MATLAB to automatically change the current directory *upon opening a .m file into an existing MATLAB instance*.  This is by design.  Unless you explicitly change the directory via the GUI or programattically (by `cd`), it would be very easy to run into unintended behavior (e.g. loading/saving files in the wrong place or using the wrong set of .m files).

However, note that after opening an .m file, you can click the "Run" button that will give you a choice to either change to the directory or add the files parent directory to the path:

[image]